# How to solve dependency conflict between js-data-angular and js-data-http

Tags: npm, jsdata, npm-shrinkwrap, js-data-angular

I'm currently working on a project, the project has 2 npm packages installed:
`js-data-http` and `js-data-angular`.

The problem is js-data-http requires `js-data@>=3.0.0` and js-data-angular requires `js-data@>=2.0.0 <3`. I've looked through all versions of both packages and couldn't find any version that matches the dependency for js-data.

With that dependency conflict I can't generate a npm-shrinkwrap, has anyone else gone through this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've figured it out, I had to set the packages in package.json to these versions:

```
"jquery": "2.2.1",
"js-data": "2.8.2",
"js-data-angular": "3.1.0"
```

Then I was able to successfully generate npm-shrinkwrap.json without conflicts, I am not sure why npm wasn't able to automatically install these three packages without conflicts though.